# How to show scroll from div fixed w100% h100%

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello my first post on SO
i'm designing web page using bootstrap

the problem is on the menu page (the sticky on right)
check it here orlandolab.hol.es

the menu page work fine on my pc / laptop but  something wrong when it viewed on mobile (just resize the browser then click the menu) the menu not scroll able

css :

```
    .navigasiku{
position: fixed;
top: 0;
/*left: 0px;*/
left: 100%;
opacity: 1;
width: 100%;
/*display: none;*/
padding-top: 6%;
height: 100%;
background: ‪#‎31302F‬;
z-index: 333;
}
```

thx before[plese check this pic for the markup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltmtX.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You'll get the best responses by posting a minimal version of your code, with clear examples of what you have tried. Posting code examples in your question is generally preferable to links to your site or images. See here for more: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: in this movile view the scrool not working https://scontent-sin1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/13754687_10205565400529157_8258555094555229960_n.jpg?oh=f14658cfc8616690207e169135bcb965&oe=582A5AAD

to view the rest menu 

https://scontent-sin1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/13754638_10210101908734612_5326892480464139825_n.jpg?oh=e2dcf13f35cb8612d276bb0c38780990&oe=5829CEA0

Answer (score 0):

You have to check whether the menu page, the one that is sticky on right, does support changing width and height. In another expression, if it uses the @media in the css code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `bootstrap` then **you should not be using width and height** settings. You should be using the classes `col-lg-*` (large), `col-md-*` (medium), `col-sm-*` (small), `col-xs-*` (extra small). The sizes refer to the screen width breakpoints.

In bootstrap the page is split into 12 columns. If you had 3 `div`s on a desktop and wished to have them displayed in line evenly across the screen you would add the class `col-lg-4`.

You can mix different breakpoint classes, for example, to have them take up half the width on a tablet, you might do something like this:

`<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">...</div>`

Each `div` would then take up a third of the width of the screen. Check out [bootstrap  documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) about this.